# How to bulk find and replace from a list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to bulk find and replace from a list with data over 60K rows in Google Sheets. Below are the data.

**Existing Data**

- Sheet Name: Keyword list
- Column A: wrong words that should be replaced
- Column B: correct words

---

- Sheet Name: Item name
- Column A: original_item name
- Column B: correct_item name (what I wanna get)

**What I want to achieve**

- Step1. Find if each item name contains wrong word that should be
  replaced (wrong word can be more than 1)
- Step2. Replace those wrong words with column B from Sheet-Keyword
  list

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

due to your extra large dataset try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(A2:INDEX(A:A, MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A))),'Keyword list'!A2,'Keyword list'!B2) ,'Keyword list'!A3,'Keyword list'!B3) ,'Keyword list'!A4,'Keyword list'!B4) ,'Keyword list'!A5,'Keyword list'!B5) ,'Keyword list'!A6,'Keyword list'!B6) ,'Keyword list'!A7,'Keyword list'!B7) ,'Keyword list'!A8,'Keyword list'!B8) ,'Keyword list'!A9,'Keyword list'!B9) ,'Keyword list'!A10,'Keyword list'!B10) ,'Keyword list'!A11,'Keyword list'!B11) ,'Keyword list'!A12,'Keyword list'!B12) ,'Keyword list'!A13,'Keyword list'!B13) ,'Keyword list'!A14,'Keyword list'!B14) ,'Keyword list'!A15,'Keyword list'!B15) ,'Keyword list'!A16,'Keyword list'!B16) ,'Keyword list'!A17,'Keyword list'!B17) ,'Keyword list'!A18,'Keyword list'!B18) ,'Keyword list'!A19,'Keyword list'!B19) ,'Keyword list'!A20,'Keyword list'!B20) ,'Keyword list'!A21,'Keyword list'!B21) ,'Keyword list'!A22,'Keyword list'!B22) ,'Keyword list'!A23,'Keyword list'!B23) ,'Keyword list'!A24,'Keyword list'!B24) ,'Keyword list'!A25,'Keyword list'!B25) ,'Keyword list'!A26,'Keyword list'!B26) ,'Keyword list'!A27,'Keyword list'!B27) ,'Keyword list'!A28,'Keyword list'!B28) ,'Keyword list'!A29,'Keyword list'!B29) ,'Keyword list'!A30,'Keyword list'!B30) ,'Keyword list'!A31,'Keyword list'!B31) ,'Keyword list'!A32,'Keyword list'!B32) ,'Keyword list'!A33,'Keyword list'!B33) ,'Keyword list'!A34,'Keyword list'!B34) ,'Keyword list'!A35,'Keyword list'!B35) ,'Keyword list'!A36,'Keyword list'!B36) ,'Keyword list'!A37,'Keyword list'!B37) ,'Keyword list'!A38,'Keyword list'!B38) ,'Keyword list'!A39,'Keyword list'!B39) ,'Keyword list'!A40,'Keyword list'!B40) ,'Keyword list'!A41,'Keyword list'!B41) ,'Keyword list'!A42,'Keyword list'!B42) ,'Keyword list'!A43,'Keyword list'!B43) ,'Keyword list'!A44,'Keyword list'!B44) ,'Keyword list'!A45,'Keyword list'!B45) ,'Keyword list'!A46,'Keyword list'!B46) ,'Keyword list'!A47,'Keyword list'!B47) ,'Keyword list'!A48,'Keyword list'!B48) ,'Keyword list'!A49,'Keyword list'!B49) ,'Keyword list'!A50,'Keyword list'!B50) ,'Keyword list'!A51,'Keyword list'!B51) ,'Keyword list'!A52,'Keyword list'!B52) ,'Keyword list'!A53,'Keyword list'!B53) ,'Keyword list'!A54,'Keyword list'!B54) ,'Keyword list'!A55,'Keyword list'!B55) ,'Keyword list'!A56,'Keyword list'!B56) ,'Keyword list'!A57,'Keyword list'!B57) ,'Keyword list'!A58,'Keyword list'!B58) ,'Keyword list'!A59,'Keyword list'!B59) ,'Keyword list'!A60,'Keyword list'!B60) ,'Keyword list'!A61,'Keyword list'!B61) ,'Keyword list'!A62,'Keyword list'!B62) ,'Keyword list'!A63,'Keyword list'!B63) ,'Keyword list'!A64,'Keyword list'!B64) ,'Keyword list'!A65,'Keyword list'!B65) ,'Keyword list'!A66,'Keyword list'!B66) ,'Keyword list'!A67,'Keyword list'!B67) ,'Keyword list'!A68,'Keyword list'!B68) ,'Keyword list'!A69,'Keyword list'!B69) ,'Keyword list'!A70,'Keyword list'!B70) ,'Keyword list'!A71,'Keyword list'!B71) ,'Keyword list'!A72,'Keyword list'!B72) ,'Keyword list'!A73,'Keyword list'!B73) ,'Keyword list'!A74,'Keyword list'!B74) ,'Keyword list'!A75,'Keyword list'!B75) ,'Keyword list'!A76,'Keyword list'!B76) ,'Keyword list'!A77,'Keyword list'!B77) ,'Keyword list'!A78,'Keyword list'!B78) ,'Keyword list'!A79,'Keyword list'!B79) ,'Keyword list'!A80,'Keyword list'!B80) ,'Keyword list'!A81,'Keyword list'!B81) ,'Keyword list'!A82,'Keyword list'!B82) ,'Keyword list'!A83,'Keyword list'!B83) ,'Keyword list'!A84,'Keyword list'!B84) ,'Keyword list'!A85,'Keyword list'!B85) ,'Keyword list'!A86,'Keyword list'!B86) ,'Keyword list'!A87,'Keyword list'!B87) ,'Keyword list'!A88,'Keyword list'!B88) ,'Keyword list'!A89,'Keyword list'!B89) ,'Keyword list'!A90,'Keyword list'!B90) ,'Keyword list'!A91,'Keyword list'!B91) ,'Keyword list'!A92,'Keyword list'!B92) ,'Keyword list'!A93,'Keyword list'!B93) ,'Keyword list'!A94,'Keyword list'!B94) ,'Keyword list'!A95,'Keyword list'!B95) ,'Keyword list'!A96,'Keyword list'!B96) ,'Keyword list'!A97,'Keyword list'!B97) ,'Keyword list'!A98,'Keyword list'!B98) ,'Keyword list'!A99,'Keyword list'!B99) ,'Keyword list'!A100,'Keyword list'!B100) ,'Keyword list'!A101,'Keyword list'!B101) ,'Keyword list'!A102,'Keyword list'!B102) ,'Keyword list'!A103,'Keyword list'!B103) ,'Keyword list'!A104,'Keyword list'!B104) ,'Keyword list'!A105,'Keyword list'!B105) ,'Keyword list'!A106,'Keyword list'!B106) ,'Keyword list'!A107,'Keyword list'!B107) ,'Keyword list'!A108,'Keyword list'!B108) ,'Keyword list'!A109,'Keyword list'!B109) ,'Keyword list'!A110,'Keyword list'!B110) ,'Keyword list'!A111,'Keyword list'!B111) ,'Keyword list'!A112,'Keyword list'!B112) ,'Keyword list'!A113,'Keyword list'!B113) ,'Keyword list'!A114,'Keyword list'!B114) ,'Keyword list'!A115,'Keyword list'!B115) ,'Keyword list'!A116,'Keyword list'!B116) ,'Keyword list'!A117,'Keyword list'!B117) ,'Keyword list'!A118,'Keyword list'!B118) ,'Keyword list'!A119,'Keyword list'!B119) ,'Keyword list'!A120,'Keyword list'!B120) ,'Keyword list'!A121,'Keyword list'!B121) ,'Keyword list'!A122,'Keyword list'!B122) ,'Keyword list'!A123,'Keyword list'!B123) ,'Keyword list'!A124,'Keyword list'!B124) ,'Keyword list'!A125,'Keyword list'!B125) ,'Keyword list'!A126,'Keyword list'!B126) ,'Keyword list'!A127,'Keyword list'!B127) ,'Keyword list'!A128,'Keyword list'!B128) ,'Keyword list'!A129,'Keyword list'!B129) ,'Keyword list'!A130,'Keyword list'!B130) ,'Keyword list'!A131,'Keyword list'!B131) ,'Keyword list'!A132,'Keyword list'!B132) ,'Keyword list'!A133,'Keyword list'!B133) ,'Keyword list'!A134,'Keyword list'!B134) ,'Keyword list'!A135,'Keyword list'!B135) ,'Keyword list'!A136,'Keyword list'!B136) ,'Keyword list'!A137,'Keyword list'!B137) ,'Keyword list'!A138,'Keyword list'!B138) ,'Keyword list'!A139,'Keyword list'!B139) ,'Keyword list'!A140,'Keyword list'!B140) ,'Keyword list'!A141,'Keyword list'!B141) ,'Keyword list'!A142,'Keyword list'!B142) ,'Keyword list'!A143,'Keyword list'!B143) ,'Keyword list'!A144,'Keyword list'!B144) ,'Keyword list'!A145,'Keyword list'!B145) ,'Keyword list'!A146,'Keyword list'!B146) ,'Keyword list'!A147,'Keyword list'!B147) ,'Keyword list'!A148,'Keyword list'!B148) ,'Keyword list'!A149,'Keyword list'!B149) ,'Keyword list'!A150,'Keyword list'!B150) ,'Keyword list'!A151,'Keyword list'!B151) ,'Keyword list'!A152,'Keyword list'!B152) ,'Keyword list'!A153,'Keyword list'!B153) ,'Keyword list'!A154,'Keyword list'!B154) ,'Keyword list'!A155,'Keyword list'!B155) ,'Keyword list'!A156,'Keyword list'!B156) ,'Keyword list'!A157,'Keyword list'!B157) ,'Keyword list'!A158,'Keyword list'!B158) ,'Keyword list'!A159,'Keyword list'!B159) ,'Keyword list'!A160,'Keyword list'!B160) ,'Keyword list'!A161,'Keyword list'!B161) ,'Keyword list'!A162,'Keyword list'!B162) ,'Keyword list'!A163,'Keyword list'!B163) ,'Keyword list'!A164,'Keyword list'!B164) ,'Keyword list'!A165,'Keyword list'!B165) ,'Keyword list'!A166,'Keyword list'!B166) ,'Keyword list'!A167,'Keyword list'!B167) ,'Keyword list'!A168,'Keyword list'!B168) ,'Keyword list'!A169,'Keyword list'!B169) ,'Keyword list'!A170,'Keyword list'!B170) ,'Keyword list'!A171,'Keyword list'!B171) ,'Keyword list'!A172,'Keyword list'!B172) ,'Keyword list'!A173,'Keyword list'!B173) ,'Keyword list'!A174,'Keyword list'!B174) ,'Keyword list'!A175,'Keyword list'!B175) ,'Keyword list'!A176,'Keyword list'!B176))
```

and give it a few seconds to complete...

this formula was generated by "formula generator"

in your `Keyword list` sheet add column C then paste this in C2:

```
={""; "=INDEX("&QUERY(FILTER(IFERROR('Keyword list'!A2:A/0, "SUBSTITUTE("), 'Keyword list'!A2:A<>""),,9^9)&"A2:INDEX(A:A, MAX((A:A<>"""")*ROW(A:A)))"&
 QUERY(FILTER(IFERROR('Keyword list'!A2:A/0, ",'Keyword list'!A"&ROW('Keyword list'!A2:A)&",'Keyword list'!B"&ROW('Keyword list'!A2:A)&")"), 'Keyword list'!A2:A<>""),,9^9)&")"}
```

next copy C3 and paste into your `Item name` sheet into B2 cell